# Content model is not working in 4.2.f

Tags: share, config, alfresco, content-model

Okay, so I had a working content model and share config in alfresco community 4.2.e. I had to reinstall alfresco and I updated to version 4.2.f. When I start tomcat I can log into alfresco, but when I try to load share it takes like 10 minutes to load and when it has loaded and I try to login it says "not availible or wrong login" after 3 minutes.

Here is the content model: http://pastebin.com/2wMJe3YL

.And the share config: http://pastebin.com/n1YK6i60

--edit1--

The alfresco.log: http://pastebin.com/PaiAUv9n

The alfrescotomcat-stdout(date).log: http://pastebin.com/RZ4fVJ8G
In the 2nd log I noticed it says refused connection, can the problem be that I changed some ports on the reinstallation from alfresco?

-- end edit1--

Alfresco does work with no content model and share config used and Alfresco works with the standard content model and share config.

Thanks in advance.

Solution: The problem was that I thought that the reinstall of alfresco would be enough to change the ports and it is, but I forgot to add some code in MY share config. The code I mean can be found here: https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Changing_Default_Port_Configuration 
thanks to: Gagravarr

Comment: Anything helpful in your `alfresco.log` file about the problem?

Comment: Those logs indicate that Share thinks Alfresco lives at `http://localhost:8080/` - is that the case? Any firewalling blocking it? etc

Comment: Alfresco is currently running on localhost:8088/share, because I changed the ports with the reinstall of alfresco. Also the firewall is not a problem here and I can confirm that the tomcat is running fine on localhost:8088/.

Comment: Did you tell Share that Alfresco is on a different port? Only your logs suggest you didn't...

Comment: Well, for school we need to run the alfresco tomcat next to the eclipse tomcat, so I reinstalled alfresco and selected advanced install. Then I changed every port to port+1 so there would be no conflicts. Maybe that's the problem, but my teammembers also can't run this content model/share config on their alfresco

Comment: There's tonnes of documentation provided by Alfresco on installation and configuration, including how to set it up for non-standard ports. [Here's the top hit from Google](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Changing_Default_Port_Configuration) which should cover you, as will many others!